# Compare country-specific effects in a time fixed effects model with company observations

Tags: interaction, fixed-effects-model

I am analysing the effect of employee education (EE) on corporate financial performance (CFP) in a fixed-effects model. I have data for American and Chinese companies and I have the following equation:

$$CFP_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 EE_{it} + \beta_2 \text{CountryDummy}_{it} + \text{further ctrl vars} + v_{it} + u_i$$

The CountryDummy takes the value 1 if the company is American and 0 if it is Chinese.

I now want to compare the different effect of EE on CFP in the two countries. Can I do that with this equation or do I have to run two models? If I can do it, do I just look at $\beta_2$ and if it is positive it means the effect in the U.S. is higher than in China?

Comment: What ist $it$? What are $u$ and $v$?

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this would be to introduce country specific coefficients on $EE_{it}$, such that the model is $cfp_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1CD_{it} + \beta_2 EE_{it} + \beta_3CD_{it}\cdot EE_{it} + ... + v_{it} + u_i$.